# String Sql for code behind

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert

i have a string that is a `CommandText` for `SqlCommand` like this:

```
string SqlCopySyntax = "insert into Question ([Body], [O1], [O2], [O3], [O4], [ocorrect], [oselected], [time],[bookrange], [UserID], [CourseID], [code]) select [Body], [O1], [O2], [O3], [O4], [ocorrect], [oselected], [time],[bookrange], @userid, [CourseID], [code] from Question where UserID = 9999999999 and code=@selectedcode";
```

i now i want to replace select part with a new select command.
it's new select command:

```
with q as (select q.*, row_number() over (partition by [Bookrange], [level] order by newid()) as seqnum from Question q ) select * from q where  UserID = 9999999999 and code=@selectedcode;
```

how should i replace this?

Comment: What do you mean?  The selected columns should match those of the table you are inserting to.

Comment: the result of the second code is same as select command in the first code. i just dont know how to copy that

Comment: The WITH in your second query is returning an additional column - seqnum - so the following select * from q has an additional column. You don't seem to be doing anything with seqnum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of the query you want is:

```
with q as (
      . . .
     )
insert into Question(. . .)
    select . . .
```

That is, the `with` goes before the `insert`, not before the `select`.

Comment: sorry i couldn't :\
`string SqlCopySyntax = "with q (as (select q.*, row_number() over (partition by [Bookrange], [level] order by newid()) as seqnum from Question q ) select * from q where  UserID = 9999999999 and code=@selectedcode) insert into Question ([Body], [O1], [O2], [O3], [O4], [ocorrect], [oselected], [time],[bookrange], [UserID], [CourseID], [code]) ";`

Comment: @MahdiHesari . . . There is no paren before the `as`.  And the `select` goes *after* the `insert`, not before.  First the `with`, then the `insert`, then the `select`.